# Is there a way to autocomplete variables in VS Code while debugging in Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, air

does anyone know if there is a way for VS Code to recognize the variables defined in my Go program while I am debugging (for autocomplete)? For example, in this case, when typing "po" it came out to complete "port" in the debug console (as happens in interpreted languages).

[image]

I am remote debugging a docker container using air.
Thank you